# How do you connect the new MacBook Air to the Cinema Display?

Tags: macbook-pro, cinema-display

The MacBook Air has the magsafe and a USB port on one side of the chassis and the mini display and another USB port on the other side of the chassis.  Does the 3-port cable for the Cinema Display work, seeing as how the magsafe and the mini display are on opposite sides instead of all lined up like on the MacBook Pro?  If so, is it graceful or ungainly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it works, but it's not graceful, it's ungainly:

[image]

Source: [Apple Insider](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/10/30/review_apples_new_11_6_inch_and_13_3_inch_macbook_air_late_2010.html&page=3)

Comment: The USB is there for the webcam, microphone, speakers, and USB ports in the display. Besides, even if USB were eliminated, you would still have the MagSafe and the Mini DisplayPort on opposite sides of the MacBook Air.

Comment: o.0 How did you make the awesome image?!

Comment: thanks kyle! Image is borrowed from the review at Apple Insider.

Comment: I suspect I know why TwelveSouth, in their marketing literature showing MacBooks in BookArcs sitting next to Cinema Displays, omits the cabling.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know myself, but a little google-fu revealed the 
[answer](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/10/30/review_apples_new_11_6_inch_and_13_3_inch_macbook_air_late_2010.html&page=3) (hat tip: AppleInsider, scroll down for image on page.)